# Jquery : get attribute of corresponding class

Tags: jquery

I have a JSON which includes the following,

```
OverlaySpaceID = 1, id = "example-overlay1", px = 0, py = 0, width = 100, height = 100, className = "highlight" ,location = "https://www.google.co.in"
```

I parse json using the following code,

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "Get",
     async: false,
     dataType: "json",
     url: '***/OverlayJson',
     success: function (data) {
         over = data;
     },
     error: function (httpReq, status, exception) {
         alert(status + " " + exception);
     }
 });
```

I use JSON in dzi image as follows

```
OpenSeadragon({
    id: "example-zoomit-tilesource",
    prefixUrl: "openseadragon/images/",
    tileSources: [{
        Image: {
            xmlns: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2008',
            Url: "http://cache.zoom.it/content/WwI0_files/",
            Format: 'jpg',
            Overlap: "0",
            TileSize: "256",
            ServerFormat: "Default",
            Size: {
                Width: "5816",
                Height: "3961"
            }
        },
        overlays: over //json 
    }, ]
});
```

JSON is mapped to a dzi image as overlays.When i click on it i need value of 'location'
    field in JSON.

```
jQuery(function () {
    setTimeout(bindtooltip, 2000);
});

function bindtooltip() {

    jQuery('.highlight').click(function () {

        var status = $(this).attr('id') //works fine
        var loc = $(this).attr('location') // not working
        alert(status);
        alert(loc);
        // window.location.href=loc;
    });
}
```

How can i get location?

Please see [the link](http://applicate.co.nz/opensea/indexx.html)

Comment: I don't see when you're reading from your json

Comment: @ErmaIsabel, is it possible to paste your code in jsfiddle.net. and share the link

Comment: @SAM Please see the above link. Itz live site. sorry, I am not familiar with jsfiddle

Comment: @ErmaIsabel, hey, i could able to see any location attribute when typed $('.highlight'); in console. I got so many <a href="#/overlay/example-overlay1" id="example-overlay1" class="highlight" style="left: 0px; top: 27px; position: absolute; display: block; width: 14px; height: 14px;"></a>

Comment: @SAM yeah, you are right. The a tags are bound by openseadragon plugin. Is it possible to get location from json with the id?

Comment: @ErmaIsabel, good to hear that, can you please share, how u did it, curious to know :)

Comment: What do you mean `location`? Isn't it `href` attribute?

Comment: @SAM Posted my answer. Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the output by changing my bindtooltip() function to the following one:

```
 function bindtooltip(){ 

         jQuery('.highlight').click(function(){

                    var status = $(this).attr('id');
                       alert(status);

   $.getJSON('***/OverlayJson', function(data) {
              var items = [];
               $.each(data, function(e) {
                  if(status ==$(this).attr('id'))
                              { items.push(data[e].location);
                                       window.location.href =items;
                               }
                  });


           });
```